# Angular 2: "Expected the operants to be of similar type or any" linting error

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I have a shared service file which defines a variable liks this:

```
export class SharedService {
    activeModal: String;
}
```

Then I have a component file that imports the service and defines it:

```
constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {
}
```

In that component's template file I check the value of the modal:

```
<div *ngIf="sharedService.activeModal === 'login'"></div>
```

Everything works fine, but in the editor, the sharedService.activeModal === 'login' part get's a red squiggly line under it and hover over it shows this linting error:

```
[Angular] Expected the operants to be of similar type or any
property sharedService of ModalComponent
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Wild guess from someone who doesn't use Angular: try lowercase `string` in the declaration of `activeModal`.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. If you answer it in the main thread I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try lowercase `string` (the primitive, rather than the wrapper object type `String`) in the declaration of `activeModal`.

Answer (score 1):

For those that have the same error but the solution doesn't apply to you, make sure you are not comparing enums with strings, if so, make a member to your class and assign the enum to it, so you would have:

```
class LalaComponent {
  someEnum = SomeEnum;
  randomValue: SomeEnum;
}
```

and in html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="randomValue === someEnum.option1" >
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score -8):

You can set to remove any future errors if you want to add extra type

```
activeModal: any
```